# AWS Cloudwatch Logstream - What is the key, and how can I set it when getting the logstream

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

This is a very specific one. I want to parametrize the versions so I can call directly a logstream but, on the logstream name, after the version there's a key that I don't know what it represents, and how I can call it so it can be autosetted at the moment of my request.

This is and example of the logstream name:

```
2018/12/10/[80]3a8d841b7b0c4e30a6bad6e4f606bXXX
```

And this is the class I'm working on (it's messy sorry I'm a newie).

```
import boto3
import time
import json
from Classes.pyEnv import environment

clientlambda = boto3.client('lambda')
clientlog = boto3.client('logs')
lambdaname = 'ExampleLambda'

aliases_response = clientlambda.get_alias(
    FunctionName=lambdaname,
    Name=environment
)
json_dict = json.dumps(aliases_response)
version_number = json.loads(json_dict)
version = version_number["FunctionVersion"]

response = clientlog.get_log_events(
    logGroupName='/aws/lambda/' + lambdaname,
    logStreamName=time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d/') + "[" + version + "]" + 
'3a8d841b7b0c4e30a6bad6e4f606bXXX')
print(response)
```

Any help will do, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot determine the log stream names of your Lambda log groups.

But you don't need to specify a log stream if you use [`filter_log_events`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html) or [`start_query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_StartQuery.html) instead of [`get_log_events`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html).